# Get variable inside function and use to start another function

Tags: php, variables

I have the following function that I invoke when I submit a HTML form, along the lines of `send_msg($user_N, $body_input, $subject_input);`

```
function send_msg($user_id, $title, $message){
$args = array( 'recipients' => $user_id, 'sender_id' => bp_loggedin_user_id(), 'subject' => $title, 'content' => $message );
messages_new_message1( $args );
}

function messages_new_message1( $args = '' ) {

  // Parse the default arguments.
  $r = bp_parse_args( $args, array(
    'sender_id'  => bp_loggedin_user_id(),
    'thread_id'  => false,   // False for a new message, thread id for a reply to a thread.
    'recipients' => array(), // Can be an array of usernames, user_ids or mixed.
    'subject'    => false,
    'content'    => false,
    'date_sent'  => bp_core_current_time(),
    'error_type' => 'bool'
  ), 'messages_new_message' );

  // Bail if no sender or no content.
  if ( empty( $r['sender_id'] ) || empty( $r['content'] ) ) {
    if ( 'wp_error' === $r['error_type'] ) {
      if ( empty( $r['sender_id'] ) ) {
        $error_code = 'messages_empty_sender';
        $feedback   = __( 'Your message was not sent. Please use a valid sender.', 'buddypress' );
      } else {
        $error_code = 'messages_empty_content';
        $feedback   = __( 'Your message was not sent. Please enter some content.', 'buddypress' );
      }

      return new WP_Error( $error_code, $feedback );

    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  // Create a new message object.
  $message            = new BP_Messages_Message;
  $message->thread_id = $r['thread_id'];
  $message->sender_id = $r['sender_id'];
  $message->subject   = $r['subject'];
  $message->message   = $r['content'];
  $message->date_sent = $r['date_sent'];

  // If we have a thread ID...
  if ( ! empty( $r['thread_id'] ) ) {

    // ...use the existing recipients
    $thread              = new BP_Messages_Thread( $r['thread_id'] );
    $message->recipients = $thread->get_recipients();

    // Strip the sender from the recipient list, and unset them if they are
    // not alone. If they are alone, let them talk to themselves.
    if ( isset( $message->recipients[ $r['sender_id'] ] ) && ( count( $message->recipients ) > 1 ) ) {
      unset( $message->recipients[ $r['sender_id'] ] );
    }

    // Set a default reply subject if none was sent.
    if ( empty( $message->subject ) ) {
      $message->subject = sprintf( __( 'Re: %s', 'buddypress' ), $thread->messages[0]->subject );
    }

  // ...otherwise use the recipients passed
  } else {

    // Bail if no recipients.
    if ( empty( $r['recipients'] ) ) {
      if ( 'wp_error' === $r['error_type'] ) {
        return new WP_Error( 'message_empty_recipients', __( 'Message could not be sent. Please enter a recipient.', 'buddypress' ) );
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }

    // Set a default subject if none exists.
    if ( empty( $message->subject ) ) {
      $message->subject = __( 'No Subject', 'buddypress' );
    }

    // Setup the recipients array.
    $recipient_ids = array();

    // Invalid recipients are added to an array, for future enhancements.
    $invalid_recipients = array();

    // Loop the recipients and convert all usernames to user_ids where needed.
    foreach ( (array) $r['recipients'] as $recipient ) {

      // Trim spaces and skip if empty.
      $recipient = trim( $recipient );
      if ( empty( $recipient ) ) {
        continue;
      }

      // Check user_login / nicename columns first
      // @see http://buddypress.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/5151.
      if ( bp_is_username_compatibility_mode() ) {
        $recipient_id = bp_core_get_userid( urldecode( $recipient ) );
      } else {
        $recipient_id = bp_core_get_userid_from_nicename( $recipient );
      }

      // Check against user ID column if no match and if passed recipient is numeric.
      if ( empty( $recipient_id ) && is_numeric( $recipient ) ) {
        if ( bp_core_get_core_userdata( (int) $recipient ) ) {
            $recipient_id = (int) $recipient;
        }
      }

      // Decide which group to add this recipient to.
      if ( empty( $recipient_id ) ) {
        $invalid_recipients[] = $recipient;
      } else {
        $recipient_ids[] = (int) $recipient_id;
      }
    }

    // Strip the sender from the recipient list, and unset them if they are
    // not alone. If they are alone, let them talk to themselves.
    $self_send = array_search( $r['sender_id'], $recipient_ids );
    if ( ! empty( $self_send ) && ( count( $recipient_ids ) > 1 ) ) {
      unset( $recipient_ids[ $self_send ] );
    }

    // Remove duplicates & bail if no recipients.
    $recipient_ids = array_unique( $recipient_ids );
    if ( empty( $recipient_ids ) ) {
      if ( 'wp_error' === $r['error_type'] ) {
        return new WP_Error( 'message_invalid_recipients', __( 'Message could not be sent because you have entered an invalid username. Please try again.', 'buddypress' ) );
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }

    // Format this to match existing recipients.
    foreach ( (array) $recipient_ids as $i => $recipient_id ) {
      $message->recipients[ $i ]          = new stdClass;
      $message->recipients[ $i ]->user_id = $recipient_id;
    }
  }

  // Bail if message failed to send.
  $send = $message->send();
  if ( false === is_int( $send ) ) {
    if ( 'wp_error' === $r['error_type'] ) {
      if ( is_wp_error( $send ) ) {
        return $send;
      } else {
        return new WP_Error( 'message_generic_error', __( 'Message was not sent. Please try again.', 'buddypress' ) );
      }
    }

    return false;
  }


/**
 * Fires after a message has been successfully sent.
 *
 * @since 1.1.0
 *
 * @param BP_Messages_Message $message Message object. Passed by reference.
 */
  do_action_ref_array( 'messages_message_sent', array( &$message ) );

  // Return the thread ID.
  return $message->thread_id;
}
```

**At the end of this function `messages_new_message1`** there is a line that says `return $message->thread_id;`.

I want to take the thread_id variable and put it into this function:

```
messages_delete_thread(thread_id,bp_loggedin_user_id());
```

I have tried to extract the variable `thread_id` but it seems to return empty. I want to initiate the `messages_delete_thread` at the end of `messages_new_message1`. How can I get this variable into the next function whilst still within the previous one?

I tried ending `messages_new_message1` like this:

```
// Return the thread ID.
// return $message->thread_id;  <- commented out as I don't want to end here
messages_delete_thread($thread_id,bp_loggedin_user_id());
}
```

but it didn't work so I'm guessing its either because I am reference the thread_id incorrectly and/or not starting the next function properly. I want this function inside messages_new_message1 because I need to loop send_msg().

Comment: `messages_new_message1( $args );` is RETURNING the id. so you can assign it to a variable and use it anywhere in the new context: `$thread_id = messages_new_message1( $args );`

Comment: @JoshuaK ok, so do I replace line 3 of `send_msg` with `$thread_id = messages_new_message1( $args );` then do `messages_delete_thread($thread_id,bp_loggedin_user_id());`?

Comment: yes. that's the way it works

Comment: @JoshuaK Excellent thank you :)

Comment: you're welcome. I wont write an answer for this. your question is too big and has so much information that isn't important for the real point, so just delete the question when your question is answered at this point.